# VIrtual base function called in base class, C++

Tags: c++

I have a class:

```
class B
{
public:
  FuncCallingFoo();

protected:
   virtual Foo (const arg argument);
}:
```

Now, function Foo is used within the body of class B, i.e. it gets called somewhere in the definition of FuncCallingFoo.

I also have class A, which inherits from B and has it's own implementation of Foo:

```
class A:B
{
...

protected:
   Foo (const arg argument);
};
```

Let's say I create an instance of class A:

```
A a;
```

Furthermore, assume I do the following call:

```
a.FuncCallingFoo();
```

will this result in the implementation of Foo from class A being called?

Comment: That sounds like something you could easily try yourself, doesn't it? I'm not sure where the problem is

Comment: You could have tried it in less time than it took you to go here, write the question, and wait for an answer.

Comment: Indeed, it takes 2 mins to try this out: https://onlinegdb.com/S1vfUgtd7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because you have declared `Foo` as protected in `class A` and `B` and you have not requested for `public` inheritance: `class A:B` (Yes, this is still valid C++).

Actually your program won't compile (after fixing the default return values and argument errors) due to this issue.

See: [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

Comment: Aha, I see, but by changing to class A: public B, that should solve the issue, I guess?

Comment: Well, in that case yes, `A::foo` will be called